# Visual Studio formatting Strings as VB.NET code

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have some MySQL written as String in my VB.NET application.
Sometimes Visual Studio (2015 Community) changes the format of some parts of the string that it thinks its a keyword.

Example.:

```
Command.CommandText = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `table_name`"
```

is changed to:

```
Command.CommandText = "DROP TABLE If EXISTS `table_name`"
```

In this case it is just annoing and not harmful, but I can think of situations where this could cause some problems. Case sensitive string comparison, for instance. Another problem is that distracts from the real modifications when using a version control.

To me its seems like a bug in the current release. For now how can I avoid this?

Comment: How are you declaring your `CommandText`? Are you putting in the quotes first and then typing out your query ***OR*** are you typing it out first and then wrapping it in the quotes? If you put the first quote in and then start typing it will pick up the `IF` and change it as the string isn't closed yet, I think that is part of the refactoring VS does...

Comment: I'm putting the quotes first. When I'm writing it, it is fine. The problem is that after is saved and committed to Git, it changes the format by itself.

Comment: Does `Git` show the lowercase or is it uppercase? If it is fine in Git then its changing on the way out and if not somehow `Git` is changing it, ***that is not likely though***. Can you try: Tools > Options > Text Editor > Basic > Advanced and then look for Pretty Listing (reformatting) of code and uncheck...? This is interesting as `CommandText` is a String...

Comment: @Zaggler The only "suspicious" option that I found is Tools > Options > Basic > Advanced > Pretty listing (reformatting) of code. If I disable that, VS won't format any of my code anymore.

Comment: Not sure at this point, I can't get it to reformat my `IF` it must be a setting or something. I wish I could be more of help.

Comment: That's very strange. I don't suppose you're doing a search-and-replace of "IF" to "If" and the scope is larger than you intended, are you?

Comment: @AndrewMorton haha, no, of course not. Is not only the "If" that's replaced, but also "Not","And","Or" etc.

Comment: @mathiasfk It was a slight possibility... :) Does the same thing happen if you assign the SQL text to a variable and then... like `Dim sql As String = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS \`table_name\`" : Command.CommandText = sql`? Are you using [`Option Strict On`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) so that you can see if the compiler is confused by something?

Comment: If I remember correctly, somebody already asked this question before... I'll see if I can find it.

Comment: Found it: [**VB.Net corrupted strings - IDE Incorrectly interpreting a string as code**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35343537/vb-net-corrupted-strings-ide-incorrectly-interpreting-a-string-as-code).

Comment: @VisualVincent Thanks! Surely is the same problem, although I'm not totally convinced that it happened like he described in the answer. I'll pay attention to it the next days so hopefully the next time it happens I'll be able to track back to what was the cause.

Comment: Try it out. Remove a necessary double-quote or add one in the wrong place, then move to another line of code (which would cause VB.NET's pretty listing to reformat it all) and see what happens. I can't confirm anything because I can't try it due to that I still use Visual Studio 2010. :)